# FreeNAS btsync Web GUI password

Tags: freenas

I recently installed the btsync on my FreeNAS box. Everything seems to be working fine, but I went back to log-in to the btsync web GUI and I can't remember the password. I must have forgotten to save it anywhere.

How do I reset the btsync web GUI password?

- **btsync:** 1.3.94
- **freenas:** 9.2.1.5

Comment: Did you manage to restore it or reset somehow?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I had a conversation on the FreeNAS forums and had no luck either. https://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/freenas-btsync-web-gui-password.21597/#post-126474

Comment: I was actually able to solve my problem, when I looked at that `btsync.conf` I was able to figure out the username, which it turned out I had wrong, and I was actually using the correct password, so everything worked out.

Answer (score -1):

I have never installed that particular plugin before but.. It will either be in its database or in a config file somewhere..  you need to go into the freenas jail folder and route around for a file which looks like it could contain a password. 
If it is a database then you will need to open it in sqlite, phpmyadmin etc. dependant on what type of database it is.

Usually, you can log into the nas via SSH using CoreFTP (you need to enable SSH in the services and setup CoreFTP). The you can browse to where your "btsync" jail is stored (usually "/mnt//jails/btsync_1") and then it is probably going to be inside this jail folder under "usr/pbi//" and somewhere in this area it will be.

Sorry I can't give exact instructions. :-)